# Update not working with id attribute Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, youtube-api

I've got below URL with get attributes sending request to the controller:

```
http://localhost:3000/videos/new/save_video?video_id=16&status=200&id=PhTHHldZJJQ
```

Constoller:

```
def save_video
    @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
    if params[:status].to_i == 200
      @video.update(:yt_youtube_id => params[:id].to_s, :is_complete => true)
      Video.delete_incomplete_videos
    else
      Video.delete_video(@video)
    end
    redirect_to videos_path, :notice => "video successfully uploaded"
  end
```

However I'm getting this error somehow:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /videos/new/save_video
Couldn't find Video with id=PhTHHldZJJQ
```

Is there a reason why it's not finding from `:video_id`?

I cannot figure this out...

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord ids are integers. You've passed in a string to `find` which won't convert to an integer, so it will always fail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's saving into `:yt_youtube_id` instead which is varchar 255 column. Does it matter? Interestingly when I take `id=` out from url it works

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it's saving into :yt_youtube_id". Did you redefine the primary key for the ActiveRecord? In any event, at least if you didn't redefine the primary key, when you don't provide a named parameter for `find`, it will search for the value of the `id` column and expect an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is trying to search the video using `:id` and not `:video_id`. It is possibly another gem (like `CanCan`), which might be trying to load the video before the action starts, in a filter. Or it might be something else in the controller, can you post the full code of the controller?

If you just want this to work, use `:id` as the variable to send the video id, instead of `:video_id`.